# Ada 2012 and the GNAT GPS IDE Debugger Can't Find Source File

Tags: ada, gnat-gps, ada2012

I'm working with a simple hello world single .adb file program in Ada 2012 using the GPS IDE under Windows 7/64. If I keep all the object and source files together everything works. **I did** have to go to the project properties Switches tab and select the Ada tab and **enable the 'Debug Information' checkbox**.

Now I want to organize my project a little better and put the object files in their own directory. I used the project properties *Objects* tab and changed the setting from `.` to `ojb`. I can build and run. Now when I go to debug and click on a line in hello.adb I get the "No source file named hello.adb. I'm guessing that it's looking in the obj directory. I tried issuing a `set directory` command and gave the absolute path to the parent folder. A subsequent `show directories` command shows that the folder containing my `hello.adb` file is now in the path but still no joy. I can no longer set a breakpoint. This doesn't seem like that unusual an operation, I suspect there is another higher level way to specify the source path for the debugger. Anyone know what it is, or any tips on getting this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPS itself does not do the debugging. It spawns a command line debugger named gdb for that purpose. You could try running GPS with --traceon=GVD.OUT (or alternatively, and often simpler on Windows, change the %USERPROFILE%.gps\traces.cfg file and add "GVD.OUT=yes").
This will log all communications between GPS and gdb in %USERPROFILE%.gps\log.*, which might be helpful in understanding why gdb is not outputting the correct full path for the files.
Please also double-check that "-g" is indeed passed to the compiler (perhaps after removing all files from obj)

Comment: I can't be positive what fixed the problem but I think it was that last parenthetical thought! I went into project properties and enabled under the Build tab the switch that re-compiles when switches are changed. I also turned on the Debug information flag here (which I'm guessing turns it on for both gcc and gnatlink). Once that was done the debug breakpoints could be set without directly manipulating gdb at all. Thanks.

Comment: I had to run "clean" before recompiling project to get it to work, after that all works well.